# SQL Azure ELMAH Delete Statement taking a long time

Tags: sql-server, azure, elmah

We've got a weekly cleanup job that deletes ELMAH entries older than 3 months however the job keeps timing out as the statement takes so long. The table has no triggers, no FKs and 2 non-clustered indexes.

```
DELETE FROM ELMAH_Error where [Application] = 'XXXXX' AND TimeUtc < CONVERT(datetime, '20160422')
```

Locally it takes about 9 seconds to delete 13k records, in Azure to delete the same number of records it's currently at 15 minutes and counting. The instance is an S3 so not the best or the worst in terms of performance, and it performs absolutely fine on much more complicated queries.

Is this really to be expected performance for a delete or is there something I can do to improve it?

As per request in comments I'm adding session info:

```
session_id  request_id  start_time  status  command sql_handle  statement_start_offset  statement_end_offset    plan_handle database_id user_id connection_id   blocking_session_id wait_type   wait_time   last_wait_type  wait_resource   open_transaction_count  open_resultset_count    transaction_id  context_info    percent_complete    estimated_completion_time   cpu_time    total_elapsed_time  scheduler_id    task_address    reads   writes  logical_reads   text_size   language    date_format date_first  quoted_identifier   arithabort  ansi_null_dflt_on   ansi_defaults   ansi_warnings   ansi_padding    ansi_nulls  concat_null_yields_null transaction_isolation_level lock_timeout    deadlock_priority   row_count   prev_error  nest_level  granted_query_memory    executing_managed_code  group_id    query_hash  query_plan_hash statement_sql_handle    statement_context_id    dop parallel_worker_count   external_script_request_id
64  0   2016-07-22 16:00:25.280 suspended   DELETE  0x0200000011544C309C7171CC58E181C91A38650CF0B7103A0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  70  230 0x0600060011544C3060702EDD6600000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  6   1   D137311B-80AB-4E17-BC86-DBBEA03244D7    0   IO_COMPLETION   288 IO_COMPLETION       2   1   20682237    0x440031003300370033003100310042002D0038003000410042002D0034004500310037002D0042004300380036002D004400420042004500410030003300320034003400440037    0   0   772 70871   0   0x8092E7FD3A7C2D84  6   32169   103713  2147483647  us_english  mdy 7   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   2   -1  0   0   0   0   0   0   2000000024  0xE627D5B8AD4C8E22  0x7D10726F72195BFD  0x09009C7171CC58E181C91A38650CF0B7103A0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  9   1   NULL    NULL

waiting_task_address    session_id  exec_context_id wait_duration_ms    wait_type   resource_address    blocking_task_address   blocking_session_id blocking_exec_context_id    resource_description
0x8092E7FD3A7C2D84  64  0   289 IO_COMPLETION   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Can you replace session id of the query  and update your question with output of below  queries..

Comment: select * from sys.dm_exec_requests where session_id=querysessionid  

select * from sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks where session_id=querysessionid

Comment: Forgive me, how do I know what the querysessionid is?

Comment: If you are running from SSMS,you can see at right hand corner  and it will have your name,then brackets ..EX:thegameiswar(240)